# How to filter multiple dataframes and append a string to the save filenames?

Tags: python, string, pandas, variables, rename

- The reason I'm trying to accomplish this is to use lots of variable names to create lots of new variable names containing the names of the original variables.
- For example, I have several pandas data frames of inventory items in each location.

  - I want to create new data frames containing only the the negative inventory items with `'_neg'` appended to the original variable names (inventory locations).
  - I want to be able to do this with a for loop something like this:

```
warehouse = pd.read_excel('warehouse.xls')
retail = pd.read_excel('retailonhand.xls')
shed3 = pd.read_excel('shed3onhand.xls')
tank1 = pd.read_excel('tank1onhand.xls')
tank2 = pd.read_excel('tank2onhand.xls')

all_stock_sites = [warehouse,retail,shed3,tank1,tank2]

all_neg_stock_sites = []
for site in all_stock_sites:
    string_value_of_new_site = (pseudo code):'site-->string_value_of_site' + '_neg'
    string_value_of_new_site = site[site.OnHand < 0]
    all_neg_stock_sites.append(string_value_of_new_site)
```

- to create something like this

```
# create new dataframes for each stock site's negative 'OnHand' values
warehouse_neg = warehouse[warehouse.OnHand < 0]
retail_neg = retail[retail.OnHand < 0]
shed3_neg = shed3[shed3.OnHand < 0]
tank1_neg = tank1[tank1.OnHand < 0]
tank2_neg = tank2[tank2.OnHand < 0]
```

- Without having to type out all 500 different stock site locations and appending `'_neg'` by hand.

Comment: Have you tried using a dict?

Comment: Thanks for your response!! This is certainly the simple answer I overlooked...however, the one from Trenton McKinney will suit me better so I can load an entire list of files all at once as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) from the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to create a list of existing files

  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
  - [`.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent)
  - [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)
  - [`.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix)
- Use [`f-strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) to update the file names

  - [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- Iterate through each file:

  1. Create a dataframe
  2. Filter the dataframe.  An error will occur if the column doesn't exist (e.g. `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'OnHand'`), so we put the code in a [`try-except`](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) block. The [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement, continues with the next iteration of the loop.
  3. Check that the dataframe is not [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html).  If it's not empty then...
  4. Add the dataframe to a dictionary for additional processing, if desired.
  5. Save the dataframe as a new file with `_neg` added to the file name

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# set path to top file directory
d = Path(r'e:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\stock_sites')

# get all xls files
files = list(d.rglob('*.xls'))

# create, filter and save dict of dataframe
df_dict = dict()
for file in files:
    # create dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    try:
        # filter df and add to dict
        df = df[df.OnHand < 0]
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(f'{file} caused:\n{e}\n')
        continue 
    if not df.empty:
        df_dict[f'{file.stem}_neg'] = df
        # save to new file
        new_path = file.parent / f'{file.stem}_neg{file.suffix}'
        df.to_excel(new_path, index=False)

print(df_dict.keys())

>>> dict_keys(['retailonhand_neg', 'shed3onhand_neg', 'tank1onhand_neg', 'tank2onhand_neg', 'warehouse_neg'])

# access individual dataframes as you would any dict
df_dict['retailonhand_neg']
```

Comment: Very informative, I have not used the pathlib module before seems like that will kill many birds with one stone.  Love, learning new ways of doing things!

Comment: @CBear12 Treating the path like an object with methods is a lot easier than trying to slice strings, I think.

Comment: I would still like to find a way to directly access the string of a variable and/or function name if that's possible? I've come across a few other use cases for that where dictionaries wouldn't fly with code that's already written.

Comment: @CBear12 Use the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function on a string. For example, where `df` is a dataframe, `eval('df')` works.  Also, `eval('str(1)')`.

Comment: ```for site in all_stock_sites_neg_onhand:
    x = eval('site')
    print(x)``` just prints the entire dataframe not the name of the dataframe which is what I want

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to not use variable names as the "keys" to the data, but rather assign them proper names, in a tuple or dict.

So instead of:

```
warehouse = pd.read_excel('warehouse.xls')
retail = pd.read_excel('retailonhand.xls')
shed3 = pd.read_excel('shed3onhand.xls')
```

You would have:

```
sites = {}
sites['warehouse'] = pd.read_excel('warehouse.xls')
sites['retail'] = pd.read_excel('retailonhand.xls')
sites['shed3'] = pd.read_excel('shed3onhand.xls')
...etc
```

Then you could create the negative keys like so:

```
sites_neg = {}
for site_name, site in sites.items():
  neg_key = site_name + '_neg'
  sites_neg[neg_key] = site[site.OnHand < 0]
```

Comment: Much appreciated for your response!  This is certainly a very direct and appropriate answer to my question, with no need for installing any new packages or any other imports!  Thanks.